# How to pass two arguments in input for infer_signature in mlflow

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model

Need infer_signature for model registry in mlflow for bert in pytorch.

Currently I am working on BertForTokenClassification and Mlflow for tracking.

My model looks like this :

```
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', 
                                                   num_labels=len(id2label),
                                                   id2label=id2label,
                                                   label2id=label2id)
model.to(device)
```

My model takes two inputs (ids and mask) which look like this.

```
sentence = "My name is john cena"
inputs = tokenizer(sentence, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=MAX_LEN, return_tensors="pt")

# move to gpu
ids = inputs["input_ids"].to(device)
mask = inputs["attention_mask"].to(device)
# forward pass
outputs = model(ids, mask)
```

I am registering mlflow like this :

```
with mlflow.start_run():
    for param in run_params:
        mlflow.log_param(param, run_params[param])
    for metric in run_metrics:
        mlflow.log_metric(metric, run_metrics[metric])
    signature = infer_signature(model_input = (ids.numpy(),  mask.numpy()),  model_output = model(ids, mask)[0].detach().numpy())
    mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model, "final_model", registered_model_name = "ner-classifier", signature=signature)
    
    mlflow.log_artifact('ConMat24.png', "confusion_metrix")
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: ('Expected one of the following types:\n- pandas.DataFrame\n- pandas.Series\n- numpy.ndarray\n- dictionary of (name -> numpy.ndarray)\n- pyspark.sql.DataFrame\n', "- scipy.sparse.csr_matrix\n- scipy.sparse.csc_matrix\n- str\n- List[str]\n- List[Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]]]\n- Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]]\n- bytes\nbut got '<class 'tuple'>'")
```

I search solution for the problem but I didn't get the answer.
Can anyone have any solution for this and alternative way for register the model please mention here.